# On certain conda commands error: 'Image not found'

Tags: python, macos, command-line, anaconda, conda

These error messages may have been caused by an Xcode update I just did recently but I am not sure. I'm running MacOS 10.15.4.

This is the error I receive upon running `conda info` in my terminal.

```
(base) Kevin-Brysons-MacBook-Pro:~ kevinbryson$ conda info
```

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/download.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
  `$ /Users/kevinbryson/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda info`
```

I am getting similar error reports upon running `conda env list`, but not `conda list`.
I have the normal anaconda3 distribution and have not seen issues like this with anaconda before. I think I can just wipe the install directory at `~/opt` but I would rather not have to redo all my settings. I've seen similar issues like https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6183 but their solutions did not work for me despite the similar situation (I tried running the `conda update -c rdonnellyr -c main --all` command.